# Hacking WATIR for traces

Tags: watir

I want to put event hooks into WATIR so every time it does a page load it calls a method on the new page.

Where would I go about inserting this hook? Sorry, I am somewhat naive about how WATIR interfaces with IE over COM.

Naively I want to get a screenshot and HTML dump at each page load that I can post process.

Comment: Is this just for IE (ie using watir-classic) or also for Firefox/Chrome/etc (ie using watir-webdriver)?

Comment: IE only using watir-classic for now. Trying to code up an open source replacement for some dynatrace functionality http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/11/04/5-steps-to-automate-browser-performance-analysis-with-watir-and-dynatrace-ajax-edition/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by using `Watir::Browser#add_checker` method - http://rubydoc.org/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/Browser#add_checker-instance_method

It works the same with watir-classic or watir-webdriver.